# Visualforce InlineEdit on repeat pageblockTable Save Cancel buttons not updating

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable, repeat, inlineeditsupport

I have a VF page with a repeating pageblock within which is an apex:detail section and a pageblockTable. Both the detail section and the table have inlineEdit support activated.

The detail section displays the buttons correctly and updates so no problem there. I placed the Save and Cancel buttons in the repeating pageBlock section and they do show when I doubleclick any of the updateable fields on the grid. When I click the 'Save' button though it doesn't save the changes for the table row. Do I need to write code for the saveButton event? I thought it would do the automatic save for the record in the table row.

The first image shows the pageblock in which the repeating pageblocks occur, before doubleclick in the table.

[image: Before double click and edit]

The 2nd image shows that the inlineEdit function allows editing and brings up the Save and Cancel buttons. Clicking Save does not save the table row - what am I doing wrong?

[image: During edit on the table]

```
    <apex:form >

    <apex:sectionHeader title="Call Cycle Schedule" subtitle="{!CallCycle.Name}" />
    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.CallCycle__c.Tab, $ObjectType.CallCycle__c)}">Back to list: CallCycles</apex:outputLink>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Call Cycle Detail">
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">

            <apex:commandButton id="PrintAdmin" action="PrintCallCycle" title="Print Call Cycle" value="Print Admin Call Cycle" 
                                onclick="window.open('/apex/CallCyclePrint?id={!CallCycle.Id}');return false;" />

            <apex:commandButton id="PrintRep" action="PrintCallCycle" title="Print Call Cycle" value="Print Rep Call Cycle" 
                                onclick="window.open('/apex/CallCyclePrintRepTable?id={!CallCycle.Id}');return false;" />
            <apex:commandButton id="CCActivitiesListView" action="{!GetActivities}" title="Call Cycle Activities ListView" value="Call Cycle Activities ListView" 
                                onclick="window.open('/apex/CallCycleListView?id={!CallCycle.Id}');return false;" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="" collapsible="false">
            <apex:outputField id="Name" value="{!CallCycle__c.Name}" />
            <apex:outputField id="Date" value="{!CallCycle__c.Date__c}" />
            <apex:outputField id="SalesPerson" value="{!CallCycle__c.SalesPerson__c}" />
            <apex:outputField id="CycleStart" value="{!CallCycle__c.CycleStart__c}" />
            <apex:inputCheckbox id="HideContacts" label="Hide Unselected Contacts" styleClass="hideContacts" value="{!HideContacts}" />
            <apex:outputField id="CycleEnd" value="{!CallCycle__c.CycleEnd__c}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Call Cycle">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton id="AddToCallCycle" action="{!AddToCallCycle}" title="Add New Account" value="Add New Account to Call Cycle" styleClass="center" />
            <apex:commandButton id="updateAllNewDate" action="{!UpdateCCADateAll}" title="Update All New Date" value="Update All Appointments with New Date" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="" collapsible="false">
            <apex:inputField id="Account" value="{!AddCallCycleActivity.Account__c}" label="Add a new Account" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField label="New Appointment Date for All in Call Cycle" id="theAllDate" styleClass="theDate" value="{!UpdateCCADateAll.EventDate__c}" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField id="NewDateTime" value="{!AddCallCycleActivity.EventDateTime__c}" label="Date/Time of Appointment for new Account" required="false"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Call Cycle Events">

        <apex:actionFunction name="rerenderDetail" rerender="detail"/>

        <apex:repeat value="{!CallCycleActivitiesEx}" var="activity">
            <apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit">
                <apex:outputPanel id="detail">
                    <apex:detail subject="{!activity.CallCycleActivity.Id}" relatedList="false" inlineEdit="true" title="false"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" value="Save" style="display:none"/>
                    <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" style="display:none"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageblockTable styleClass="cc_row" width="95%" rowClasses="odd,even" value="{!activity.CallCycleActivity.CallCycleActivityContacts__r}" var="contact">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" event="ondblclick" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                    <apex:column styleclass="cc_col5" headerValue="CRM">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox title="{!contact.Id}" value="{!contact.IsSelected__c}" styleClass="checkContact"
                                            onclick="updateDisplay(this, '{!contact.Id}');" />{!contact.Contact__r.AccredoCRMGroup__c}
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column styleclass="cc_col8" headerValue="Contact Name">
                        <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.View, contact.Contact__r.Id)}" target="_blank">{!contact.Contact__r.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column styleclass="cc_col5" headerValue="Phone Number" value="{!contact.Contact__r.Phone}"/>
                    <apex:column styleclass="cc_col8" headerValue="Mobile Phone" value="{!contact.Contact__r.MobilePhone}"/>
                    <apex:column styleclass="cc_col8" headerValue="Email" value="{!contact.Contact__r.Email}"/>
                    <apex:column styleclass="cc_col5" headerValue="Department" value="{!contact.Contact__r.Department}"/>
                    <apex:column styleclass="cc_col5" headerValue="Title" value="{!contact.Contact__r.Title}"/>
                    <apex:column styleclass="cc_col3" headerValue="Confirm">
                        <apex:outputField styleClass="lineId" value="{!contact.Contact__r.ConfirmAppointment__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column styleclass="cc_col3" headerValue="Include">
                        <apex:outputField styleClass="lineId" value="{!contact.Contact__r.IncludeInCallCycle__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column styleclass="cc_col3" headerValue="Exclude">
                        <apex:outputField styleClass="lineId" value="{!contact.Contact__r.Exclude_from_Call_Cycle__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column styleclass="cc_col5" headerValue="Last Visit">
                        <apex:outputField styleClass="lineId" value="{!contact.Contact__r.LastCallCycleVisit__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column styleclass="cc_col5" headerValue="Frequency" >
                        <apex:outputField styleClass="lineId" value="{!contact.Contact__r.CallCycleFrequency__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column styleclass="cc_col5" headerValue="Method">
                        <apex:outputField styleClass="lineId" value="{!contact.Contact__r.PreferredContactMethod__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column styleclass="cc_col8" headerValue="Pref Day">
                        <apex:outputField styleClass="lineId" value="{!contact.Contact__r.Preferred_Day__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>

                </apex:pageblockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:repeat>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

Comment: It would be of much help if you could paste the controller code which contains save method. If you are using save method of standardController, thats where the error will be, because save method on standard controller works only on single record not on list of records.

Comment: Ah Vigneshwaran, so is that my problem - so I need to code a custom save button? I don't have one in the controller at the moment as I thought it would automatically save as a standard function. What would I need to do there - loop through all the rows or will it only work on those that have been edited?

Comment: You need to have a extension controller and override save method to save all the records. One problem is it cannot determine which record is edited, so you have to update all records.